# Set key in a Javascript generator function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, iterator, generator

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to set up the key in a symbol iterator, this is the code I have so far:

```
let james = {
    name: 'James',
    height: `5'10"`,
    weight: 185
};

james[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    for (let key in this) {
        yield this[key];
    }
}

let iterator = james[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 'James'
console.log(iterator.next().value); // `5'10`
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 185
```

the issue I'm having is for example:
the call of iterator.next() should print

```
{"value": "James", "key": "name", "done": false}
```

but I'm getting

```
{"value": "James", "done": false}
```

I'd like to set somehow the "key" as the same way I'm setting up the "value".

I checked to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*), but I haven't seen any docs related to this.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

the use case for the question was basically turning the **James object** into an **iterable object**, it doesn't matter "how", so my first try was to use a generator, then I realized I needed to print the object in this format:

```
{ value: 'James', key: 'name', done: false }
{ value: '5\'10"', key: 'height', done: false }
{ value: 185, key: 'weight', done: true }
```

which is not a standard way to do it, so I had to create a custom method to "implement" the behavior:

thanks to @loganfsmyth for pointing me in the right direction, I came up with this simple solution:

```
let james = {
    name: 'James',
    height: `5'10"`,
    weight: 185
};

james[Symbol.iterator] = function (){
   const keys = [];
   for (let key in this) {
      keys.push({'key':key, 'value':this[key]});
    }
  return {
    next(){
      let {key,value} = keys.shift();
      return {value,key,done:keys.length===0};
    }
  }
}

let iterator = james[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 'James'
console.log(iterator.next().value); // `5'10`
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 185
```

Comment: `the call to iterator.next() should print ...` why? Iterators explicitly yield `value/done` objects, you can't have other fields on there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to yield both the key and the value, you'd need to yield an array with two items, e.g.

```
yield [key, this[key]];
```

then the `.value` on the object would be a key/value pair.

Also note that this behavior is similar to what you get from `Object.entries(james)` which is a new function added in ES2017, except that it returns an `Array`.

If explicitly want

```
.next()
```

to return an object with both `key`, `value` and `done`, then the answer is you can't do that with a generator. That's not the API that generators provide, and it's not the iterator protocol defined in ES6, so you shouldn't be using an iterator to try to do this.

You could certainly do

```
james.makeCustomThing = function(){ 
  const pairs = [];
  for (const key in this) pairs.push([key, this[key]]);
  return {
    next(){
      if (pairs.length === 0) return {done: true};

      let [key, value} = pairs.shift();
      return {key, value, done: false};
    },
  };
};
```

but then it's not an iterator anymore, it's just a custom thing you've defined yourself.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I need to have this object when doing a print over next => {"value":"James","key":"name","done":false} and not an embeded key value pair

Comment: But that's not how iterators work, so would you rather follow the standard, or would you like that output, because you can't have both. You also haven't given any information on the usecase, so it's hard to provide much guidance beyond that.

Comment: basically, the use case is turning the `james` object into an iterable object, it doesn't matter "how", but my first try was like using a generator, then I realized, I needed to print the object I mentioned before, I'll try a different approach

Comment: Having the iterator return pairs of items is the standard approach for iterating over objects. That's why all the ES* APIs have standardized on `.entries()` functions that do that. `.entries` exists for `Array`, `Object`, `Map` and `Set`. You have not stated why you _need_ to have a `.key` instead of an array. If it's because you want to sometimes be able to iterate just the values, you can have two different types of iterator functions for the two cases.

Comment: @jack.the.ripper: If you don't follow the standard, then things like `for...of` or `Array.from` won't work as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it. The interface for iterators in ES6 is unchangeable:

```
interface IteratorResult {
  done: boolean;
  value: any;
}
interface Iterator {
  next(): IteratorResult;
}
interface Iterable {
  [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator
}
```

And generators work only with it. Whatever you yield it's going to be in `value`.

Answer (score 1):

I modified @jack.the.ripper code to make use of Object.keys and next with arrow function, so we can make use of this.

```
const james = {
    name: 'James',
    height: `5'10"`,
    weight: 185
};

james[Symbol.iterator] = function (){
  const keys = Object.keys(this)
  return {
    next: () => {
      let key = keys.shift();
      return {value: this[key], key, done:keys.length===0};
    }
  }
}

let iterator = james[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 'James'
console.log(iterator.next().value); // `5'10`
console.log(iterator.next().value); // 185
```