# Javascript generator functions using function factories

Tags: javascript

I think i have a grasp of the generator functions, don't know if i would really use them but i found something that Douglas Crockford said that is particularly interesting. In this video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxnYQRuLX7Q ) at 26:00 he says that generators can be replicated using a factory type pattern and normal functions. I am unable to formulate 'how' that might be possible. Any program proving that would be cool to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Crockford said:

Generator is a huge mistake of ES6, with a bit of weird magic and weird-looking

```js
function* counter() {
  let index = 0;
  while (true) {
    index += 1;
    yield index;
  }
}

const gen = counter();

gen.next().value    // 1
gen.next().value    // 2
gen.next().value    // 3
```

And this is how we should be doing it by using higher-order function:

```js
function counter() {
  let index = 0;
  return () => {
    index += 1;
    return index;
  };
}

const gen = counter();

gen()   // 1
gen()   // 2
gen()   // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

> generators can be replicated using a factory type pattern and normal functions.

Yes. A generator function is just a function that returns a generator when called. A generator is just an object with `next`, `throw` and `return` methods. You can create such a thing without special syntax.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45806552/1048572)'s an example, [there](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[es6]+code%3A"next()+%7B") are a few more (notice generators are a special case of iterators, so usually you will see an iterator with only `next` implemented, but the same pattern could be extended to generator methods).